# How to correct use <h:selectManyCheckbox> and <f:selectItems> with Criteria

Tags: java, jsf, seam, criteria

I'm learning Seam since few days and I want to create simple filter using 
`<h:selectManyCheckbox>` and `<f:selectItems>` tags. 
Here is frag xhtml file with tags:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{userSessionsSession.selected}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{usersSessionsPage.logLevelList}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

In UserSessionSession I have:

```
private List<String> selected; 

    public List<String> getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(List<String> selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
```

UserSessionPage:

```
private List<SelectItem> logLevelList;

public List<SelectItem> getLogLevelList(){
        if(logLevelList == null){
            logLevelList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
            Collection<MdoUserSessionDetStatus> tmpList = sessionAuditUtils.getDetailsStatusEntities();
            for(MdoUserSessionDetStatus mdo: tmpList){
                logLevelList.add(new SelectItem(mdo.getCode(), mdo.getName()));
            }
        }
        return logLevelList; 
    }
```

and in function with criteria restictions:

```
if (selected != null && !ANY_STATUS.equals(selected)) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("mdoUserSessionDetStatus.code", selected));
        }
```

When I check and submit option nothing happens and console dispalys warning:

```
 WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=filterPanelForm:j_id163[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(Conversion Error setting value 'DEBUG' for '#{userSessionsSession.selected}'. ), detail=(Conversion Error setting value 'DEBUG' for '#{userSessionsSession.selected}'. )]
```

I don't know how to correct handle this event, can any one help me?
I will be grateful.

Comment: try adding `<h:messages globalOnly="true"/>` this will show the errors on page and you wont get the logs in server with warning

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change it

```
private SelectItem[] logLevelList;

public SelectItem[] getLogLevelList(){

if(logLevelList == null){

Collection<MdoUserSessionDetStatus> tmpList =   sessionAuditUtils.
                                                    getDetailsStatusEntities(); 

logLevelList =  new SelectItem[tmpList .size() + 1];

for(MdoUserSessionDetStatus mdo: tmpList){
            logLevelList.add(new SelectItem(mdo.getCode(), mdo.getName()));
         }
     }
     return logLevelList; 
 }
```

Comment: You didn't worded clearly what exactly you have changed, so your answer is hard to understand. Based on the code, you're basically changing `List<SelectItem>` type to `SelectItem[]` (with compile errors!). This makes no sense. Both types works as good. You're also not explaining in any way *how* this solves OP's concrete problem, you're merely guessing and stabbing in the dark without really answering OP's concrete problem. This answer should be deleted. Whoever upvoted this answer is also wrong.

Comment: The code in your answer doesn't compile. There's no `add()` method on `SelectItem[]`. Further it makes absolutely no difference for `<f:selectItems>` whether you return `SelectItem[]` or `List<SelectItem>`. You you are basically not explaining/answering *anything*. You're just posting a code snippet as a shoot in the dark without really understanding the problem.